# How to efficiently get rolling windows stats from a pandas dataframe for arbitrary dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe of events like the following:

| date | user | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | Adam | 10 |
| 2021-01-01 | Bernice | 15 |
| 2021-01-02 | Adam | 5 |
| 2021-01-06 | Carl | 8 |

And a pandas Series of dates like `["2021-01-03", "2021-01-12"]`

I'm trying to collect stats about the events for the 7 days before each date in the dates series. My target output looks like this:

| date | unique_users | average_amount | total_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-03 | 2 | 10 | 30 |
| 2021-01-12 | 1 | 8 | 8 |

Is there an efficient way to do this in Pandas? This is my current solution, but it doesn't leverage pandas functions so is pretty slow:

```py
import datetime as dt

import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": [dt.date(2021, 1, 1), dt.date(2021, 1, 1), dt.date(2021, 1, 2), dt.date(2021, 1, 6)],
    "user": ["a", "b", "a", "c"],
    "amount": [10, 15, 5, 8],
    })
dates = pd.Series([dt.date(2021, 1, 3), dt.date(2021, 1, 12)])

records = []
for date in dates:
    idx = (
        (df["date"] < date)
        & (df["date"] >= date - dt.timedelta(days=7))
        )
    filtered = df.loc[idx]
    record = {
        "date": date,
        "unique_users": filtered["user"].nunique(),
        "average_amount": filtered["amount"].mean(),
        "total_amount": filtered["amount"].sum(),
        }
    records.append(record)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(records)
print(df2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach is similar to @sammywemmy but will doesn't require the dates you want to sample to be 7 days, or more, apart.

**setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": [pd.Timestamp(2021, 1, 1), pd.Timestamp(2021, 1, 1), pd.Timestamp(2021, 1, 2), pd.Timestamp(2021, 1, 6)],
    "user": ["a", "b", "a", "c"],
    "amount": [10, 15, 5, 8],
})
dates = pd.Series([pd.Timestamp(2021, 1, 3), pd.Timestamp(2021, 1, 12)])
```

**solution**

Involves [piso](https://piso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), a package with methods for pandas intervals, interval index etc

```
import piso

contained = piso.contains(
    pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(dates-pd.Timedelta("7d"), dates),
    df["date"],
).transpose()
```

`contained` is indexed by original dates in `df` and a column for each interval window.

```
            (2020-12-27, 2021-01-03]  (2021-01-05, 2021-01-12]
2021-01-01                      True                     False
2021-01-01                      True                     False
2021-01-02                      True                     False
2021-01-06                     False                      True
```

We then create a function which is applied to each column

```
def calc(col):
    filtered = df.loc[col.values]
    return pd.Series({
        "unique_users":filtered["user"].nunique(),
        "average":filtered["amount"].mean(),
        "total":filtered["amount"].sum()
    })

result = contained.apply(calc).transpose()
```

`result` looks like this

```
                          unique_users  average  total
(2020-12-27, 2021-01-03]           2.0     10.0   30.0
(2021-01-05, 2021-01-12]           1.0      8.0    8.0
```

You can change the index to be the original sample dates with

```
result.index = result.index.right
```

**note**: I am the creator of piso. Please feel free to reach out with feedback or questions if you have any.

Comment: love the abstraction offered by it; just a note to readers that there is a caveat on its use ( it does not support fully closed ends; it has to be either left closed right open, or right open left closed). Still it is a powerful tool, and efficient too, plus it can handle overlapping intervals ( I think).

Comment: @sammywemmy yeh, wanna have a beer next time I drive 2hrs south to Sydney? :D
I've added the discussions tab to the github page, might be easiest to chat there

Comment: Latest version now supports "both" and "neither" closed values for several methods including `piso.contains`.  @sammywemmy I've added some new issues to the backlog (scrappily) if there's anything there that takes your fancy.

Comment: that's great @Riley. currently contributing to another open source; once I have some time on me, I will jump in. thanks!

Comment: No worries mate

Comment: This worked great, thanks. The only problem I had was that it doesn't seem to work with python `date`s, but worked fine when I switched to `datetime`s.

Comment: Yeh that's a consequence of pandas not supporting `date` for `pandas.Interval`

Answer (score 1):

Your question looks like an interval search ( and unique values as well), in which case, you can use pandas interval index :

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
end_date = pd.to_datetime(dates)
start_date = end_date - pd.Timedelta(days=7)
intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(start_date, end_date, closed='both')
(df.assign(date = end_date[intervals.get_indexer(df.date)].array)
   .groupby('date')
   .agg(unique_users=('user', 'nunique'), 
        average_amount=('amount', 'mean'), 
        total_amount = ('amount', 'sum'))
) 
            unique_users  average_amount  total_amount
date                                                  
2021-01-03             2            10.0            30
2021-01-12             1             8.0             8
```

You might have to do a bit of filtering with the `end_date[intervals.get_indexer(df.date)]`; in the example data you shared, all values are present